# How to get JSON from a distant server in an express server?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, coffeescript

I'm looking a way to replicate the jQuery method getJSON but server side.
The server I'm using is a node.js server with express framework written in coffeescript.

The code I have client side is :

```
# To get the client IP
$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", (data) ->
      # To get more information about that IP
  $.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/" + data.ip, (fulldata) ->
    console.log fulldata))
```

The fulldata variable give me information about the client IP.

I have to avoid using JavaScript client side, so I try to do the same server side, I get the client IP doing :

```
(req, res) ->
  # To get the client IP
  req.ip
```

But after that, I have no idea how to get the fulldata in json from the freegeoip.net server.

Help, anyone ?

Comment: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.request

Comment: https://github.com/mikeal/request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Skelly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171456/skelly) solution.

So I did :

```
request = require 'request'

(...)

(req, res) ->
  url = 'http://freegeoip.net/json/' + req.ip
  request.get(url, (error, response, body) ->
    if !error 
      console.log body
  )
```

The body contains the data I need.

I'm sure the [David Fregoli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680422/david-fregoli)'s native node.js solution works also, but the Request package works perfectly and easily.

Thanks to them both.

Comment: If you are only after get requests node.js has a shortcut which is similar to the request module. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.5.2/api/http.html#http.get

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with coffeescript, however, one of Node's default libraries called http (most often used to set up a server) can make http requests

```
var request = http.request({host: 'jsonip.com', port: 80, path: '?callback=?' , method: 'GET'}, function(res){
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
    });
});
```